# Change color of active textbox?

Tags: windows-8, colors, color-theme

I restarted my Windows and suddenly all my textboxes are grey.
How can I restore them to white?

[image]

I know it's the color 150 150 150 (0x969696) but I can't find anything in the registry with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what caused that to happen, but here are the defaults for all color-related settings, found it the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors`:

```
"Window"="255 255 255"
"GradientInactiveTitle"="215 228 242"
"TitleText"="0 0 0"
"ButtonAlternateFace"="0 0 0"
"HotTrackingColor"="0 102 204"
"InactiveTitleText"="0 0 0"
"ActiveBorder"="180 180 180"
"ActiveTitle"="153 180 209"
"ButtonShadow"="160 160 160"
"InactiveTitle"="191 205 219"
"Menu"="240 240 240"
"ButtonDkShadow"="105 105 105"
"HilightText"="255 255 255"
"ButtonText"="0 0 0"
"GrayText"="109 109 109"
"InfoText"="0 0 0"
"MenuText"="0 0 0"
"MenuHilight"="51 153 255"
"Hilight"="51 153 255"
"Background"="0 0 0"
"AppWorkspace"="171 171 171"
"ButtonLight"="227 227 227"
"GradientActiveTitle"="185 209 234"
"WindowFrame"="100 100 100"
"InfoWindow"="255 255 225"
"MenuBar"="240 240 240"
"Scrollbar"="200 200 200"
"ButtonFace"="240 240 240"
"WindowText"="0 0 0"
"ButtonHilight"="255 255 255"
"InactiveBorder"="244 247 252"
```

Assuming you haven't changed anything else, you can find the one in your registry that differs and set it back to the value in the list. Reboot required.